# plotting the whole data within each facet using facet_wrap and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot line graphs for and `facet_wrap` for each dataset. What I would love to have is in light grey, transparent or something, all datasets in the background.

```
df <- data.frame(id=rep(letters[1:5], each=10),
                 x=seq(10),
                 y=runif(50))

ggplot(df, aes(x,y, group=id)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~ id)
```

[image]

This graph is how far I get, but I would love to have all the other missing 4 lines in each graph as well... In any way I try to use `facet_wrap`, I get only the data of a single line.

What I would expect is something like this for each facet.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y, group=id)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_line(data=df[1:10,], aes(x,y, group=id), size=5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's another approach:

First add a new column identical to id:

```
df$id2 <- df$id
```

Then add another `geom_line` based on the df without the original id column:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y, group=id)) + 
  geom_line(data=df[,2:4], aes(x=x, y=y, group=id2), colour="grey") +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~ id)
```

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant! I really didn't think about adding new data to a geom this way, and tried too much 'one line with all info for all observations'.

Comment: I also like this solution more than @Heroka . I still have to think a minute why it works nicely but I think this solves my issue easily...

Comment: Thank you :) Though I am sure there is a lot of equally creative ways which work here.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach. It might not be suitable for larger datasets, as we replicate the data `number_of_facets`-times.

First, we do some data-wrangling to create this desired dataframe.
    df$obs_id <- 1:nrow(df) #unique ID for each observation

```
#new data with unique ID's and 'true' facets
df2 <- expand.grid(true_facet=unique(df$id), obs_id=1:nrow(df))

#merge them
dat <- merge(df,df2,by="obs_id",all=T)
```

Then, we create a flag defining the 'true' faceted variable, and to discern background from foreground.

```
dat$col_flag <- dat$true_facet == dat$id
```

Now, plotting is easy. I've used geom_line twice instead of scales, as that was easier than to try to fix the ordering (would lead to black being plotted below grey).

```
p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=x,y=y, group=id))+
  geom_line(color="grey")+
  geom_line(dat=dat[dat$col_flag,],size=2,color="black")+
  facet_wrap(~true_facet)
```

[image]