# R ggplot - adding all data points to all facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

until now I can't find an appropriate answer, here is my short question about ggplot2 in R:

```
data(mtcars)
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=wt, fill=factor(cyl))) +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","orange","blue"))+
geom_point(size=2, pch=21)+
facet_grid(.~cyl)
```

[image]

This is all fine, now I want all data points (regardless what number cyl has) in every facet (e.g. with a smooth grey below the points)?

Thanks, Michael

Comment: Possible duplicate of [plotting the whole data within each facet using facet\_wrap and ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550411/plotting-the-whole-data-within-each-facet-using-facet-wrap-and-ggplot2)

Answer (score 16):

Here is a slight simplification that makes life a bit easier. The only thing you need to do is to remove the faceting variable from the data provided to the background `geom_point()` layer.

```r
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=wt)) + 
  geom_point(data=select(mtcars,-cyl), colour="grey") +
  geom_point(size=2, pch=21, aes(fill=factor(cyl))) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","orange","blue")) + 
  facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Using the link given by @beetroot, I was able to do something like this :

```
g1 <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=wt)) + 
  geom_point(data=mtcars[, c("mpg", "wt")], aes(x=mpg, y=wt), colour="grey") +
  geom_point(size=2, pch=21, aes(fill=factor(cyl))) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","orange","blue")) + 
  facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

This produces the plot : 
[image]

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks. I will elaborate the proposed link. Thanks also for your suggestion, but here I get: "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (60): x, y, fill" when I applied it in this way to my specific data (but data structure is the same).

Comment: @mod_che : The code that I have wrote, is this also giving you error? For me, it works fine.